# Problems utilizing MSSQL driver for PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have installed MSSQL driver on PHP , when I check my phpinfo page it surely shows me SQLSVR ENABLE. then even when i try to connect to any SQL Server database it says function does not exist.

I have also found on web a code which I am using to determine if function exists or not but its also returning function not exists , the code is:

```
<?php

if (function_exists('mssql_fetch_row')) {
echo "MSSQL functions are available.<br />\n";
} else {
echo "MSSQL functions are not available.<br />\n";
}

?>
```

Can any one help me out?

I have tried it on both IIS and XAMMP but the issue remains same.

Comment: Have you by chance installed the MSSQL PDO driver instead of the MSSQL extension?

Comment: Please quote the exact line from phpinfo()  (best copy & paste)

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution, the solution is mssql_fetch or any command starting with mssql will not work with the new drivers for SQL Server 2008.

You need to use sqlsrv_fetch command rather then mssql_command for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the mssql driver is obsolete. Microsoft supports two PHP drivers: a (cross-platform) PDO driver and SQLSRV. See this blog post [mssql vs. sqlsrv: What’s the Difference?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx)